# Make Background Service run on startup as well as every minute

Tags: android, push-notification, background-service

Currently, I have a IntentService that checks a php server for new notifications intended for the user, and a BroadcastReceiver that listens for BOOT_COMPLETED. What I wanna know is how do I combine to two to not only make the IntentService run on startup, but also make the IntentService run every minute from that point.

Also, I want to make sure that I'm sending notifications the right way. In IntentService.onHandleIntent(), I have this for sending the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), mBuilder.build());
```

Am I missing anything for this to actually create the notification? (The variables "title", "message", and "id" are already set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AlarmManager for repeated tasks.

```
// Setup a recurring alarm every half hour
  public void scheduleAlarm() {

    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);

    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
    // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
  }
```

For Detailed explanation refer https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks.

In every onReceive call of MyAlarmReceiver you can start your intentservice.
You should also read https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Thank you!!! Two things, however. 1) I can set my own interval instead of using the preset intervals (15 min, 30 min, 1 hour, 24 hours)? And 2) how does my notification code look?

Comment: 1)Yes you can set your own interval.2) Notification code looks alright. But your notification does not have any content intent set. You don't want to take any action on notification click? You should read this https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html